# How can I add my app to favourite on facebook?

Tags: facebook, tabs

I created an application and I want to share it on my table on facebook. How can I add this application to a favourite like on below image:

[image]

I can add events, notes, movies and groups. It's also choice 'search more apps', but if I choose this option it will be redirected to the application center and I do not have the option to add the application to my table.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can only add apps as “page tab” to Facebook pages, not to user profiles.

Comment: I was looking for the same thing but I've found in the documentation that it seems to be possible only for pages: [Page tab tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/)

Answer (score 0):

If you edit your app settings to include `Page Tab`, it will let you use the app on your page, but it may require some changes. For example, the size of the Fan Page apps are fixed at 810px wide or 520px wide.

The App Settings page will let you upload a custom image for the tab like your screenshot too, but this only works for Fan Pages, not user Profiles.